# How to make my scanner ignore lines ending in <dir> using java?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I have a scanner which is reading in a file, but I do not know how to make the scanner ignore lines ending in < dir >

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please edit your question to show your code.  What have you tried?  What errors are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

Use `Scanner#next` method. It will block until user inputs a non-empty string.

**Update** after the question was rephrased:

Try the following way:

```
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    scanner.useDelimiter("\r\n"); //For Windows, new line.
    String s = "";
    do {
        s = scanner.next();
    }
    while(s.endsWith("< dir >"));
```

Comment: Sorry, the question i posted was meant to say a line ending in < dir >, stack overflow didn't allow me to post it without the spaces. <dir>

Comment: So truncate only "< dir >" or skip the whole line that has "< dir >" in the end?

Comment: Skip the whole line.

Answer (score 0):

To skip lines that match a given pattern you can use, `Scanner#skip(String pattern)` method.

In your case, you want to skip input lines ending in . 
So you can call above method with following pattern `"<dir>$"`.